# Create phone conference using UCMA

Tags: c#, skype-for-business, ucma

I'm trying to create phone-conference with UCMA 5.0.

This code works fine

```
info.Mcus.Add(new ConferenceMcuInformation(McuType.AudioVideo));
info.Mcus.Add(new ConferenceMcuInformation(McuType.InstantMessaging));
info.Mcus.Add(new ConferenceMcuInformation(McuType.Meeting));
info.Mcus.Add(new ConferenceMcuInformation(McuType.ApplicationSharing));
```

But if I adding this MCU

```
info.Mcus.Add(new ConferenceMcuInformation(McuType.Phone));
```

I got an error

> The request failed with reason: mcuTypeNotAvailable

I need this MCU for external phone participants.

What is the reason for this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:
In **ConferenceScheduleInformation** object set **PhoneAccessEnabled** property to **true**.

Question closed.